# constructor in subclass with only partial parameters of superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

Hi very much a beginner on java and am working on coursework where I am trying to get my head around inheritance.  I get how constructors can be referenced from superclass using super if the parameters in the subclass match the parameters of the super class and then remaining parameters in subclass constructor are then assigned to instance variables of that subclass.
What i am confused about is what if i want to create an object of a subclass where the constructor only has partial parameters but that subclass still can refer to the methods of the super class to return its name.  An example is below which wont compile as it is expecting an input of String on top of the two strings in Car's constructor. 
Have i misunderstood something?

```
public class Vehicle{
    private String fuelType;

    public Vehicle(String fuelType){
        this.fuelType = fuelType;
    }
        public String getType(){
        return this.fuelType;
    }
}
public class Car extends Vehicle{
    private String make;
    private String model;

    public Car (String make, String model){
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
    }   
}
```

Comment: If a Vehicle has a fuelType, and if Car is a Vehicle, then Car has a fuelType too. If it doesn't, then it shouldn't extend Vehicle.

Comment: You may want to read up on the protected keyword for this: https://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/protected-keyword

Comment: The `Car` constructor needs to call the `Vehicle` constructor, because you cannot logically create a `Car` without also creating a `Vehicle`. (It's not a different vehicle, just that the car *is a* vehicle, so creating a car entails creating a vehicle.) If you don't want to accept the fuel type as a parameter to the `Car` constructor, how about passing a constant value such as `super("gasoline");`?

Answer (score 0):

You might

1. Pass a constant fuelType to the constructor
2. Create another constructor in Vehicle and initialize fuelType to some constant value.

However, in this case it doesn't make much sense to instantiate a Car object without specifying fuelType.